# Failing to add google fonts to an qt application

Tags: qt

I'm trying to add a google font to my Qt app and then deploy it with it. There isn't my info out there but with what there is I download the font, put it the folder next to `MainWindow.cpp`.

I then load it in the constructor:

```
QFontDatabase fontDB;
fontDB.addApplicationFont("./Nunito_Sans/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf");
```

And then add it to my label:

```
label->setStyleSheet("color: white;"
                        "font-size: 18px;"
                        "font-family: NunitoSans-SemiBold;");
```

But I don't see any changes.

Comment: what is the output of `qDebug() << fontDB.addApplicationFont("./Nunito_Sans/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf");`?

Comment: The output is: `-1`

Comment: Well the problem is the path, I think the .ttf is in the source code folder instead of the build folder. I recommend you change to: `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/fullpath/of/Nunito_Sans/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf");`

Comment: Okay! Now I get a 1 but my label didn't change. I am adding it correctly?

Comment: what is the output of  `int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/fullpath/of/Nunito_Sans/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf");` `qDebug() << QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id);`